# Android how to do the upward shadows

Tags: android

Android 5.0  Material Design it seems impossible.

[image: shadow screenshot]

Comment: The effect map has been attached

Answer (score 0):

You can get that kind of effect using Bottom Navigation Tab.
Try this code hope it helps you

For Bottom Navigation Tab you have to add this line into dependency

```
compile ‘com.android.support:design:25.0.0’
```

Here is MainActivity.Java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BottomBar mBottomBar;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Notice how you don't use the setContentView method here! Just
    // pass your layout to bottom bar, it will be taken care of.
    // Everything will be just like you're used to.
    mBottomBar = BottomBar.bind(this, R.layout.activity_main,
            savedInstanceState);

    mBottomBar.setItems(
            new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_recents, "Recents"),
            new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_favorites, "Favorites"),
            new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_nearby, "Nearby"),
            new BottomBarTab(R.drawable.ic_friends, "Friends")
    );

    mBottomBar.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(final int position) {
            // the user selected a new tab
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mBottomBar.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Design.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Container -->

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_favorites"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_schedules"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/text_music"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Enable/Disable click state

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_enabled="false" />
</selector>
```

Handle click event using this

```
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
                findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.action_favorites:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_schedules:

                        break;
                    case R.id.action_music:

                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add view in layout

```
<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dip"
    android:background="@drawable/drop_shadow" >
 </View>
```

add in your drawable folder  drop_shadow.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
<gradient
    android:startColor="#404040"
    android:endColor="#F1F1F1"
    android:angle="270"
    >
</gradient>
</shape>
```